How to aggregate Gcloud logs-based metric by custom time range?
I have a logs-based metric (counter) that is counting the amount of the logs per second, from a SpringBoot application running on a simple instance, I'd like to have the option to aggregate the chart by further time ranges like hours, days, weeks, and so on. I can't see any option to achieve it on the Metrics Explorer/Edit Chart screens.


Refer to this document and also go through this document which might be helpful for you.
